# Topological group: Multiplying two loops is homotopic to linking these paths?

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Let G be a topological group and let $s_1$ and $s_2$ be loops in G (both loops are based at the identity e of G). Is it true that the loop $s_1s_2$ (where the multiplication is the one of the group structure of G) is equal, in $\pi_1(G,e)$, to the loop $s_1*s_2$ where this product is given by first going around $s_1$ and then $s_2$ (i.e., do we have $[s_1s_2] = [s_1*s_2]$)? If yes, what is the proof for this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes and this is known as the Eckmann-Hilton argument. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument))

Answer (score 24):

Instead of using the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument) abstractly, you can make it explicit, as follows:

We can reparameterize the loop $s_1$ to be constant (and equal to the neutral element) on $[1/2,1]$ and $s_2$ to be constant on $[0,1/2]$. Then $[s_1 \ast s_2] = [s_1 s_2]$ and since $s_1s_2 = s_2s_1$ we also get that the fundamental group is abelian.

Comment: Well, that's just E-H argument for this situation written down explicitly, isn't it?..

Comment: Yes, but I still think that it's shorter and more intuitive this way. (Maybe I shouldn't have said *Instead*...)

Comment: I agree. (But something like _more explicitly_ would seem more... precise, indeed.)

Comment: Fixed, I hope. Thanks for pointing it out!